# $A\subseteq B\;\wedge B\cap C\subseteq A\overset{?}\implies C^c\cap A\subseteq B^c$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

$A,B,C\subseteq U$

$A\subseteq B\;\wedge B\cap C\subseteq A\overset{?}\implies C^c\cap A\subseteq B^c$

Contraposition for the expression on the right side:
$$(C^c\cap A)\subseteq B^c\iff B\subseteq (A^c\cup C),$$ 
$$A\subseteq B\implies A\subseteq B\subseteq (A^c\cup C)\iff A\subseteq C$$ 
$A\not\subseteq C$ would be a counter example.

Is this legitimate?

Comment: The implication does not hold.

Comment: Consider e.g. $U=B = \mathbb N, A= \{ 2,4 \}$ and $C = \{ 2 \}$. We have $A \subseteq \mathbb N$ and $B \cap C = C = \{ 2 \} \subseteq A$. But $C^c= \mathbb N \setminus \{ 2 \}$ and thus $C^c \cap A= \{ 4 \}$. But $B^c= \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you haven’t shown that it is possible to have $A\not\subseteq C$, and still meet the hypothesis. You should include an example. A simple example would be to have:
$$A=\{2,3\}$$
$$B=\{2,3,4\}$$
$$C=\{1,2\}$$
Then you have the hypothesis without the conclusion, which means the implication is false.

Answer (score 0):

The original statement is true iff the following statement is a tautology

[(x in A --> x in B)&[(x in B& x in C) --> x in A] ]-->[( ~ x in C & x in A )-->~x in B]

With " ~ " meaning " it is not the case that".

You can build a truth table to test this statement.

This truth table will have 8 lines , since there are 3 elementary proposiitons in the whole sentence : x belongs to A, x belongs to B and x belongs to C.

If you want to use a truth table calculator online, use the symbol "A" for " x belongs to A", the symbol "B" for " x belongs to B", etc.

This amounts to translating your original statement into the language of propositional logic.